# Has any Star Trek character appeared in all three division uniform colors?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-uniforms

Many characters have appeared in two colors.

Examples:

**Red and Gold**

- Worf --  entire seasons in each
- La Forge -- entire seasons in each
- Data -- red in several episodes, e.g. "Future Imperfect"
- Wesley Crusher -- yellow in "Parallels"
- O'Brien -- red in first season
- [Sito Jaxa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sito_Jaxa) -- cadet red and security
- Thomas Riker -- red in "Defiant"

**Red and Blue**

- Picard -- blue in "Tapestry"
- Dr. Crusher  -- red in "All Good Things"

Red and gold are pretty common and blue is harder to collect.

Has any character ever appeared in all three colors?
(or even the unlikely gold/blue combination for that matter)?

Clarification:  For characters that appeared in different uniform generations, colors are interpreted as equivalent if the color change was due to changes in uniforms.   For example, TOS-era command gold and TNG-era command red count as the same.   There were widely varying uniforms and colors in the various TOS-era films.

Comment: +1.  Any particular reason this is tagged as star-trek-voyager?  Also, are we focusing on *TNG*-era?

Comment: I guess Sito had a red/black Academy jumpsuit and then later a gold officer's uniform.

Comment: @Praxis: Yes, I've always assumed the cadet uniforms counted as red division, although I guess it could be debated whether that is 'command division'.   Is there any evidence pro or con?   (At any rate, there's no debate they are red)

Comment: http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=191002

Comment: @JohnP:   Nice find, but this seems to be focused on the actors and not the characters.   But maybe the answer is in there?

Comment: Sisko wore yellow and Dax wore red in DS9's "Trials and Tribble-ations" - just to add to your list.

Comment: @JackBNimble But the title says "three division uniform colors", they didn't switch divisions, the division colors changed between the TOS and DS9 eras. Yes, this is some extreme geek nit picking.

Comment: I found a tripod link that said there was a continuity error in the end of the original movie where McCoy and Spock wore the others uniform accidentally, can't find photo though. Most I can find is four.

Comment: According to [this chart](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/gallery/other/bens-uniform-chart.jpg) TOS Movies have 6 divisions available, each with a different color.

Comment: @muistooshort - actually, Dax wearing red would be switching Divisions. Sciences was always blue, and Dax's normal color is blue. So by wearing read she switched from DS9 Sciences to TOS Operations.

Comment: @Omegacron: Right, Dax did end up in ops-red (switching colors and divisions). The others stayed in their divisions though.

Comment: The academy uniform really doesn't count, IMHO.

Comment: I was sure this was a dupe; can't find it though

Comment: Brent spiner in a blue uniform; http://fashionablygeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/brent-spiner-spock-fresh-hell-600x328.jpg

Comment: This question has issues, I think.  Maybe it should have  been "Which character has been part of the most divisions?" or "Which character has appeared with the most uniform colors?" but not both since color meanings have changed over time.  It's too late to fix it, as all your answerers are talking about "command red", "security gold", etc.  But I saw that answer from @JohnP yesterday which I guess he had to delete; I don't see it now.  But he obviously had trouble interpreting the question.  (I'm not gonna downvote, just saying this could have been a lot tighter.)

Comment: @T-5000:   Yeah, well, as can happen, the question seemed straight forward when I asked it and then you get embroiled in technicalities as people come up with answers.   I can add a clarifying sentence.   See the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is now protected, so I can't post another answer; but Tom Paris (voy) has a red uniform in most episodes, gold in the episode "Worst case scenario", and blue in "Author, Author"

Comment: @JohnP: Your link denied hotlinks.  Can you provide it another way?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Try [this link](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/gallery/starfleet-uniforms1.htm) (Original linked image is the upper left)

Comment: @Jave:   I have unprotected the question.   If this is true for a modern(TNG)-era Star Trek character without being some obscure corner case, I would like to see that answer.  I am unable to find an image of Paris in a blue/teal uniform.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### [Kyle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kyle):

Operations (TOS: "[Wolf in the Fold"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wolf_in_the_Fold_(episode))):

[image: Kyle in red]

Sciences (TOS: "[Space Seed](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Seed_(episode))", "[Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan)"):

[image: Kyle in blue][image: Kyle in movie sciences gear]

Command (TOS: "[The Immunity Syndrome](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Immunity_Syndrome_%28episode%29)"):

[image: Kyle in gold]

### [Sulu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hikaru_Sulu):

Sciences (TOS: "[Where No Man Has Gone Before](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_No_Man_Has_Gone_Before_(episode))"):

[image: Sulu in blue]

Command (TOS: "[Arena](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arena_(episode))", "[Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country)"):

[image: Sulu in gold][image: Sulu in command white]

Operations (TOS: "[Mirror, Mirror](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror%2C_Mirror_%28episode%29)", "[Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan)" publicity shot):

[image: Mirror Sulu in red] [image: Sulu in operations gold]

### [Chekov](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pavel_Chekov):

Command (TOS: "[Spectre of the Gun](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spectre_of_the_Gun_(episode))"):

[image: Chekov in gold]

Sciences ("[Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country)"):

[image: Chekov in movie science colors]

Operations ("[Star Trek: The Motion Picture](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture)", "[Star Trek Into Darkness](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness)") (the grey backing on the Starfleet / Enterprise insignia indicates Operations / Security in the TMP uniform):

[image: TMP Chekov] [image: Into Darkness Chekov]

Comment: Epic answer, how did you find/remember Kyle in Space Seed is beyond me.

Comment: @Politank-Z : Also, great work --- for some reason, Sulu in the blue shirt in *TOS* didn't come up in my search.

Comment: @Politank-Z : And I didn't check Chekov's neck / strap colour in *STVI*.  Again, excellent!

Comment: @this He struck me as a jack of all trades, and that shot is on his Memory Alpha page (linked).

Comment: @Praxis: There, Kyle was in science-wear in TWOK.

Comment: @Politank-Z : Perfect. :-)

Comment: Of course, one of those "Operations" Sulus is from the mirror universe... The other one, though, great find.

Comment: I figured that if Abrahmsverse was going to be cited, Mirror Mirror was fair game :)

Comment: TOS shouldn't count.

Comment: @user973810 Well, it has to. I'm not about to go looking for TAS references.

Answer (score 68):

I'm gonna go for the EMH. He appeared in both the Blue and Red uniforms in the main series and his diagnostic subroutine (arguably a part of the EMH package of programs) appeared in a yellow uniform in Voy: The Swarm.

As @sidney has [pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99533/has-any-star-trek-character-appeared-in-all-three-division-uniform-colors/99545?noredirect=1#comment229159_99545), the Diagnostic Program was ultimately grafted onto the EMH prior to the other two photos below, meaning that all three are essentially the same character.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. +1 *"I'm a doctor, not a fashion model."*

Comment: The diagnostic subroutine is a bit of a stretch. It was more meant to represent Dr. Zimmerman himself, than an actual extension of the EMH, even though technically it may have been a part of the whole EMH program bundle.

Comment: @Iszi - You've hit the nail on the head. The Recovery Disk is *part* of Windows, not an entirely separate program.

Comment: I don't know, I mean, he's got that messy hair to represent basically a different character.  The EMH would remember everything the ECH did as actions by himself with new aptitudes.   Would he remember what the diagnostic subroutine did as 'himself' ?

Comment: The diagnostic program was of a completely separate matrix, which was a crucial plot point in that episode. I don't think we can count Zimmerman's hologram as the EMH here.

Comment: The quote from the episode is that "This programme contains a sophisticated diagnostic matrix specifically created for the Emergency Medical system". It seems to have been bundled into the overall EMH package. Word might not be the same program as Excel, but they're part of the same "suite" of programs.

Comment: Considering the diagnostic program was eventually "grafted" on to The Doctor, it could be argued that it was not the doctor but actually the diagnostic program that has at some time been part of all three divisions, although it's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @sidney - That's a really, really good point

Answer (score 29):

## Spock

One character who sports multiple colours is **Spock**.  He usually appears in **science blue**:

[image]

But here he is with **command gold** in the first episode of *TOS*, "Where No Man Has Gone Before":

[image]

Out-of-universe, they hadn't settled on his uniform yet.  But in-universe, it's completely compatible with the fact that he is both First Officer and Chief Science Officer, and so he is in two divisions at once.

And now here he is in **red** in *The Wrath of Khan*:

[image]

Of course, ***all*** Starfleet officers of that era wear red jackets, but Spock's uniform here is adorned with command-level brass, as he is the Captain of the Enterprise in this particular screenshot.

In a sense, command-level is **white** in the film era, designated by the white turtleneck beneath the jacket and the white shoulder strap.

In contrast, medical officers like McCoy have a dull green turtleneck and strap. Saavik is a lieutenant junior grade, and her red turtleneck and strap coincide with this.  Engineers have gold turtlenecks and straps.

[image]

So one can say that Spock is seen with three colours: **gold**, **blue**, and **white**.

Now, that's three colours but only two divisions, since gold from *TOS* and white from the film era have the same meaning.

However, since the original question question cites Sito Jaxa's red Academy jumpsuit as a divisional colour (indeed, Starfleet Academy is considered to be the [fourth division](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_division)), here is Spock with his **charcoal** instructor's uniform from the 2009 film:

[image]

So that makes for **blue** (science), **gold / white** (command), and **charcoal** (Academy instructor).

## Wesley Crusher

Counting the Academy as a Starfleet division makes **Wesley Crusher** another candidate, as @ThePopMachine points out.  Wesley wears **command red**, **operations gold**, and his **red-topped Academy jumpsuit**, all in *TNG*:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We also see Wesley in his **grey** acting ensign uniform, although it is unclear which "division" it designates (if any).

Comment: What about the grey with the ribbed collar that he wore as an acting ensign? Technically acting ensign is a rank. There were a lot of wartime promotions that were "acting" or "Brevet" until confirmed by central command, but they had full rights and privileges of said rank.

Comment: @JohnP : That's a good point.  I'm not certain which "division" acting ensign falls into, but I'll definitely add an image.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnP: I was never sure whether that was supposed to be a uniform at all. We never saw anyone else with that grey jumpsuit, and Wesley did wear [other uniform-like clothes with colored shoulder pieces](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/3/3a/Wesley_Crusher%2C_late_2364.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120802011245&path-prefix=en). For all we know, differently-colored shoulder pieces might have been just the fashion at that time (maybe even either inspired by Starfleet uniforms or vice-versa). So, maybe those were simply his civilian clothes?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I agree, but how many other acting ensigns were there?

Comment: @JohnP: Well, statistically, *shouldn't* we have seen one at some point during all the years? Or at least someone who, in some way, has a similar status as Wesley? Yet, no-one was ever seen wearing any uniform remotely similar to Wesley's outfit. Rather than assume that Starfleet has a uniform type that is unlike everything else we have ever seen in that timeframe (and that has never been proven to be "uniform" across any group of people), the suspicion that it is simply a modest civilian outfit manifests itself.

Comment: I don't recall, which color jumpsuit did Spock wear in TMP?

Comment: @Xantec : He comes aboard with Vulcan robes, but then switches to a [baby blue jumpsuit](http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/10900000/Star-Trek-The-Motion-Picture-mr-spock-10920222-725-875.jpg).

Answer (score 17):

**Lt. Leslie**

[Lt. Who What Now?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie)

Lt. Leslie has served as *deep breath*... [Duty Officer, Engineer, Helm Officer, Medical Assistant, Navigator, Science Officer and Security Officer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie#Starfleet_service).  He appeared in [57 TOS episodes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie#Appearances) and has the remarkable ability to [return from the dead several times](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie#Red_shirt) (or Dr. McCoy was drunk when he pronounced him dead) and quickly change uniforms and duties within a few minutes.

Blue / Sciences ([TOS: Where No Man Has Gone Before](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_No_Man_Has_Gone_Before_(episode)))
[image]

Red / Operations ([TOS: The Squire Of Gothos](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Squire_of_Gothos_(episode)))
[image]

Gold / Command ([TOS: The Changeling](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Changeling_(episode)))
[image]

Out of universe, Lt. Leslie is obviously the result of [TOS reusing the same stable of actors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie#Background_information) and not paying close attention to continuity.  In universe, Lt. Leslie appears to have [some very remarkable qualities](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie#Identity_Crisis) leading to some theories that he's actually several people or a remarkable alien or a quick change artist or an incredible savant.

And yes, [he does have lines and is named on screen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie#Memorable_quotes).

Comment: Good answer, but gold/green is command, red is operations, and blue is science/medical.

Comment: @JohnP Thanks, I was thinking TNG.

Comment: Is he named in *each* episode?

Comment: @Richard A quick check says no. For example, [Where No Man Has Gone Before](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/2.htm) and [The Changeling](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/37.htm).

Comment: @Schwern - Hmm. If they've simply recycled the actor (but not the character), I think I'd raise the same objection I raised with JMFB, that they're not necessarily the same person in-universe.

Comment: @Richard I'm sure the [Thermians](http://galaxyquest.wikia.com/wiki/Thermian) puzzled long and hard over how to make this one work.

Answer (score 11):

**Q.**

Appears in red in numerous episodes of TNG and Voyager, in yellow in "Hide and Q" and in blue in the Paramount-licensed video game [Star Trek: Borg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi2HO5e_oeM).

[image]

Comment: What's the canonicity of Star Trek: Borg?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Unusually high. It was written by Hilary Bader (who wrote numerous episodes of trek), directed by James Conway  (who directed several episodes of Voyager) and used the original voyager sets. Also, the entire cast are Trek actors and the game received an audio book conversion directed by Jonathan Frakes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Borg curious. Also http://www.old-games.com/download/6029/star-trek-borg

Answer (score 7):

Most likely not, but technically - Wesley Crusher.

[image: Wesley Crusher]

Picard in tapestry was an alternate time line, so I would not count that.

Comment: I love it. You are technically correct, the best kind of correct.

Comment: By the same same token, you might also want to consider [Trip](http://i31.photobucket.com/albums/c389/MikeN1138/captionsandphotomanips/Caption%20Contests/fallenhero1-1.jpg) and [Tom Paris](https://llordllama.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/capture2.jpg?w=300&h=233)

Comment: No to @Valorum.   I mean, I like the tricky answer, but you can't call it technically correct in light of the clear clarification at the end of the question.   Nice try, though.   (If we allow answers based on a technical reading of only the question and not the body, then it opens up all kinds of tricky answers.   I know.   I'm no fun.   But you try to be technical, you get technical back.)

Comment: Did we really wear such outfits in the 80's? I have vague memories that I think I may have intentionally suppressed.

Answer (score 4):

**Tom Paris**

Usually wears the red Command uniform:

[image: Tom Paris wearing red uniform]

In the episode "Worst Case Scenario (s3e25)" he wears the Gold operations uniform:

[image: Tom Paris wearing gold uniform]

And in the episode "Author, Author (s7e20) he wears the Blue science uniform (technically in a holonovel):

[image: Tom Paris wearing blue uniform]

Comment: That's not Tom Paris in the final example, it's Lt *Marseilles*

Comment: And in the second example, he's a hologram